# static member function and thread-safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, static-functions

In C++, when you have local variables in a static member function, does it mean those local variables are also implicitly static or are they really local?

example:

```
static void myClass::somefunc(int someint)
{

int myint = someint;  // is myint really a local variable or does it change due to the static qualifier at function level?


}
```

Also, different threads from a thread pool running this function, does myint need to be protected by a lock?  assuming that all values passed to it are different and have no relation to each other.

EDIT: Thanx for the answers.  Now what if I passed in a `boost::shared_ptr<T>`, knowing that this object would not be concurrently being used by another thread? (Not sure if one can really guarantee that, or can you?)

I guess a raw ptr passed in, would need some protection, if it were being used all over?

Comment: You are confused by static having two completely different meanings. You are not alone, which is perhaps why static on a standalone function is deprecated now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are local unless you declare them `static` - each invokation of the function will have its own copy of the variable and you don't need to to protect them.

Comment: Some people seem to confuse `static functions` with `static local variables`, while there is practically no relation between the two.

Comment: @T33C: You are wrong. The variable is obviously not static (even if the function is). Remove your -1

Comment: "... and you don't need to to protect them."  - I disagree with this and I am saying that it is unsafe in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: @T33C": How can another thread get concurrent access to a local variable?

Answer (score 1):

`myint` is local for `somefunc` and you don't need to protect it across threads.

Answer (score 1):

myint in your example is a local variable, every time somefunc is called myint lives. but not more than that.

myint doesn't need to be protected because its a local variable

Answer (score 1):

`myint` will truly be local.  You don't have to worry about protecting it.  A separate space will be created on the stack for `myint` for every single function call in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The `myint` variable will stay local, there is no need to protect them since each thread will not share the local variables.

Answer (score 1):

The static key-word means that the function will not be passed a hidden "this"
argument. Also the function will not have access to the class instance data.
The static qualifier of function, has no impact on function's local data.

The `static RetType SomeClass::SomeMethod(Type arg)` has the same "type" as a free function`RetType SomeFunc(Type arg)`

Regards,
Marcin